# Read char from file in SML

Tags: sml, ml

I need to read characters from a file in SML. I have this piece of code for reading integers:

```
fun readInt input = Option.valOf (TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) input)
```

Is there something equivalent for characters? I've seen that there is `Char.scan` but I am not very sure on how to use it.
Thanx in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like `Option.valOf (TextIO.input1 input)`